# Is it possible to alternate between from addresses on alpine?

Tags: alpine-linux, alpine-mail

I added a few from addresses in `Customized headers` in Alpine's configuration, that allows me to edit the `From` field when composing email.

Now I'm just writing them myself and I wonder whether there is a way (a key binding maybe) that allows me to alternate between the available from addresses?

Answer (score 0):

This was what I was able to dig up on the subject. This tutorial titled: [CHANGING YOUR FROM HEADER IN PINE](http://www.ii.com/internet/messaging/pine/changing_from/#fly).

> Changing Your From Header On the Fly
>   If you use more than one From header, you will probably want to make the one you use the most frequently your default and then specify your alternate From header on the fly. The two ways to do this are 1) to directly edit your From header when you are composing a message or 2) to set up the alternate From header as part of one of your alternate roles. These are discussed below.
>
> #### Using the `default-composer-hdrs` Variable
>
> To view your From header -- and possibly edit it -- while you are composing a message, [add the hidden feature `allow-changing-from` to your feature list](http://www.ii.com/internet/messaging/pine/changing_from/#allow) and add From to your `default-composer-hdrs` variable. For example, here's what I use for my `default-composer-hdrs`:
>
> ```
> default-composer-hdrs=From,
> Lcc,
> Attchmnt,
> Organization,
> Fcc,
> Newsgroups,
> To,
> Cc,
> Bcc,
> Subject
> ```
>
> These are the headers that will be displayed when you are composing a message. You can view these, along with other headers, by by typing ^R to view rich headers. You can edit any of these headers while you are composing a message.
>
> #### Tip
>
> Add each of your alternate From addresses to your address book and then type the address-book nickname for the alternate address that you want to use in your From header. When you press RETURN, TAB, or an arrow key the nickname will be expanded to the full address.

So based on the above it sounds like you'd use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> while composing a message.

#### References

- [CHANGING YOUR FROM HEADER IN PINE](http://www.ii.com/internet/messaging/pine/changing_from/#fly)
- [Customization and Configuration](https://www.washington.edu/alpine/faq/config.html)

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer to this question, though I appreciate this is a bit late.

This method requires marginally more set up, but is potentially quicker than the earlier answer.

Assuming the use case of multiple email addresses:

Set up a [role](https://alpineapp.email/alpine/alpine-info/roles/#setup) using `M`, `S`, `R`, `R`, `A`. An example to set up roles provided [here](https://www.schotty.com/General_Linux/Alpine_EMail_Client_Configuration/#multiple-smtp).

Navigate to [configuration options](https://alpineapp.email/alpine/alpine-info/roles/#configoptions) using `M`, `S`, `C` and set the `[X] Alternate Role (#) Menu`.

Thereafter, pressing `#` almost anywhere in Alpine allows one to `C`ompose, `R`eply, `F`orward, or [`B`ounce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message), where logically sensible, as whichever role one wishes to use.

**Please note: One may need to delete existing configuration setups for this to work. For instance, Google appears to require your existing app password be deleted.**